# Post-build event: Is there a macro for App Data?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, copy, post-build-event, appdata

A typical post-build event should look like this:

```
COPY "$(SolutionDir)Resources\abc.xyz" "$(TargetDir)"
```

Various macros exist for solution dir, output dir etc. **But how do I copy to system's special folders? Are there macros for it? I want copy to Common App Data folder**.

Why: From the client machine, my app accesses files in common appdata directory. To simulate the scenario in my development machine, I need to ensure `abc.xyz` is present in my app directory too. How do I copy `abc.xyz` from `$(SolutionDir)Resources\abc.xyz` to something like `$(App_Data)` **in post-build**?

I can manually copy paste it, every time I update the `Resources` folder, but I would like to automate it with VS.

**Update:**

I could do this with *xcopy*,

```
XCOPY "$(SolutionDir)Resources\abc.xyz" "%appdata%\MyPath\"
```

But that copies to user's local app data path, not common application data. **How do I do it for common application data?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want `%ALLUSERSPROFILE%\MyPath`. Found using `set` on the commandline btw.

Comment: note that on Windows 7 etc this defaults to c:\ProgramData, but on XP it will be different!

Comment: I know. It is indeed that varying location I want (otherwise I will hard-code it) :)